How does Spring WebFlux get a response from external service?
I am new to reactive programming with Spring and I am trying to understand it. For example we have an http integration with an other service. I have read that in reactive Spring it is possible with non-blocking socket channels and selector. In abstract way EventLoop thread handles an input request and starts executing http query, after that it does not have to wait response and it is free to handle other requests as it is non blocking.
I've read this article and I am confused about what is a callback function (I suppose it allows us not to block and handle other requests)? I don't understand how EventLoop processes external service responses because it does not wait and swithes to handle another requests.
I tried to test it with a selector and socket channels and I think abstractly EventLoop threads simply check whether events came from client or not (using selector.select() method) and then returns data. Am I correct?
